# On a single "sidewaystable" page, how to have a tabular environment on top and a few figure environments below?

Tags: floats, sidewaystable

So,

What I want is to have a sideways table and few figures below it. In a single page. As you would know it, it shifts figure on the next page. This is the dummy version:

```
    \clearpage
    \begin{sidewaystable}\centering
        \caption{Table-able}    
          \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
                A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
                A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
          \end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Yes tis a fig}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
```

Thank you in forward.
P.S. I toyed with minipage, but with no luck.

Comment: Do you want your image to be rotated as well? How wide is your table? Typically one would only use sidewaystable for a table that is too wide to fit onto a portrait page. With such a wide table on a page I can hardly imagine a textwidth wide image to fit underneath it and onto the same page. Could you please clarify on that?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution

- loads the `rotating` and `caption` packages,
- uses a single `sidewaystable` environment,
- places a wide `tabular` environment in the upper part of the page, and
- places three side-by-side `minipage` environments in the lower part of the page, with each `minipage` containing `\includegraphics` and `\captionof{figure}` directives (as well as, if needed, `\label` statements).

An additional thought -- As @egreg points out in a comment, this approach carries the following risk: The numbering of `figure` environments could be thrown off if one or more standalone `figure` floating environments are in the queue, waiting to be processed, when LaTeX encounters the start of the `sidewaystable` environment. The most satisfactor way to handle this contingency will depend on the reason *why* LaTeX chose to defer (i.e., delay) the typesetting of the `figure` floats. A brute-force solution would be to load the `afterpage` package and to encase the `sidewaystable` environment code in the following "wrapper" code

```
\afterpage{%
\clearpage  % flush all pending floats
\begin{sidewaystable} 
...
\end{sidewaystable}%
} % end of scope of \afterpage directive
```

As noted, this is a brute-force approach and, as such, need not be optimal.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{caption}  % for '\captionof' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % optional, for '\toprule' and '\bottomrule' macros

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}

\centering
\caption{Table-able}
\begin{tabular}{*{21}{c}}
\toprule
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A & A \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}  % create some vertical separation

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{First} \label{fig:aa}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{Second} \label{fig:bb}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\captionof{figure}{Third} \label{fig:cc}
\end{minipage}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd mention that the numbering of figures could be off, if a `figure` happens to be placed before the `sidewaystable` but input later, so this needs some care; the problem should be sorted out when the document is finished, of course.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for pointing out this potential issue. I've posted an addendum to my answer, to incorporate and build on your comment.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. The solution is simplet and elegant.